# How does one interpret/parse keyboard and mouse input across *nix TTYs / terminal emulators?

Tags: parsing, input, terminal, pty, terminal-emulator

I'm writing a command line app for *nix systems. I want to turn bytes on stdin into input device events, things like "Left button clickced", "upward scroll wheel tick/motion", "ctrl-alt-shift-leftarrow was pressed", and so on. I would like to do this across currently in-use virtual terminals, i.e. xterm, gnome-terminal, the linux kernel console (Ctrl-Alt-F1..6), tmux, any-of-the-above over ssh, et cetera.

I'm perfectly happy only accommodating ~99% of what people are doing for the last ~10-20 years, i.e. if someone plugs a physical VT100 into their machine and my app doesn't work on it, I'm okay with that. However, I would like to make full use of the capabilities of xterm and friends, and I would like, as much as is possible, to be able to know what the bytes on stdin mean.

How does one do this? In other words, how do I very approximately reimplement the input subsystem of ncurses?

As far as I can tell, the representation of an escape keypress on pretty much all terminals is a prefix of most e.g. arrow- and function-key escape sequences, and non-prefix-free encodings are notoriously hard to disambiguate, especially when M-x is encoded the same way as ESC followed-by x ;-)

That minor issue has been elevated to a command line ui convention by now, so be it, but more worryingly: let's say I want to build a database of known escape sequences (and a map from context, e.g. `$TERM` value, to database slice), and if my program receives an unknown input sequence I skip it. How do I tell where an escape sequence ends? As far as I can tell, that's not easily doable. I want single-character hotkeys for commands, but I don't want unknown escape sequences to trigger them.

As far as I can tell, this is approximately impossible.

My best idea is to proceed empirically: build a list of all the terminal emulators I know of, feed each of them all the valid X11 key inputs and see what comes out the other end. To the extent the terminal emulators are configurable in their X-key-to-stdio-bytes mappings, this is going to be very squishy. But as far as I can make sense of the world, this is roughly what terminfo is.

Comment: Why implement it yourself? As you said yourself, it is already implemented in many libraries such as ncurses...

Comment: @kmaork it is implemented *incompletely* in many libraries. I would like some certainty about what keys the user pressed, and I would like to support many different key presses, across a wide range of terminals. Stuff like ctrl-shift-alt-arrow is notoriously heterogeneous across terminals.

Answer (score 0):

terminfo (and termcap) provide an application with a *dictionary* of known key codes.  But those dictionaries are limited in size.  Some terminal (emulators) can provide many more than can be defined in termcap (1024 bytes) or terminfo (4096 bytes in the legacy format — perhaps the current 65536 in ncurses is enough).

Any so-called "modern" terminal will follow the convention that keys (**inputs**) are bound to something that corresponds to [ECMA-48](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ecma-48-parameter-format.html) (which addresses only **output**).  That came about partly because of keys (in particular cursor-keys) which could be interpreted in a *local mode* of the terminal.

Likely enough, a given terminal emulator does not implement *local mode* (ECMA-48 [*`SRM`*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Pm-h:Ps-=-1-2.1E54)), but [xterm](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) does that.  And because (a combination of compatibility and lack of innovation) other terminal developers follow this pattern.  This is not the only way that keys could be encoded (e.g., the mis-named [ANSI.SYS](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_D_O_S__A_N_S_I__S_Y_S_variants), whose scheme using a null character has been "invented" by a few "modern" developers).

curses/termcap applications rely upon this dictionary, without making assumptions about the format of the key encoding.  But if one (either by modifying the curses library or the curses/termcap application) chose to treat any unknown sequence of bytes as for example `KEY_UNKNOWN` if it followed the ECMA-48 pattern, then that would simplify recovery in an application.